# Horizontal scroll bar on searchkit/afform

Tags: javascript, searchkit, formbuilder

We have been using SearchKit and Form Builer (afform) to develop new reports for our teams. Some of the tables have grown to be quite extensive. The headers are becoming difficult to read because the table is only staying within the frame rather than creating a horizontal scroll bar. Does anyone know how to add a horizontal scroll bar to a SearchKit Table or to Afform?

Comment: if not already done so, perhaps ask at https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/search-improvements

Answer (score 1):

You could use some css to increase the width. On mine there already is a scrollbar but you could force it with overflow-x. So something like:

```
div.crm-search-display {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
div.crm-search-display table {
  max-width: 1500px;
  width: 1500px;
}
```